# different printf behavior with float * and int *?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

First, let me clarify that I know passing pointers as arguments to these `printf` specifiers is not correct. I am interested however in knowing what is going on in `printf` when it is done.

Using the *normal* print specifiers, `%d` for `int`, and `%f` for `float`, why is it the `int *` prints, while the `float *` will not?

For example, given these variables (unitialized):

```
int a, *pA;
float b, *pB;

pA = &a;  
pB = &b;
```

When called like this:

```
void printVar(int *a, float *b)
{
    printf("%d\n", a);//why does "a" print at all?
    printf("%d  %p\n",   a,  b);// when "b" prints only using %p
    //printf("%d  %f", a,  b);// but fails on parameter mismatch using %f
    printf("%d  %f\n"  ,  *a, *b);// prints normally (as expected)
}
```

Why do I get this?:    ("a" prints OK, but "b" prints only with %p or by passing *b)

[image]

***[edit]***  entire code to clarify and address some of the comment questions:

```
#include <ansi_c.h>

void printVar(int *a, float *b)
{
    printf("%d\n", a);//why does "a" print at all?
    printf("%d  %p\n",   a,  b);// when "b" prints only using %p
    //printf("%d  %f", a,  b);// but fails on parameter mismatch using %f
    printf("%d  %f\n"  ,  *a, *b);// prints normally (as expected)
}

int main()
{
    int a, *pA;
    float b, *pB;
    char s[100], *pS;

    pA = &a;
    pB = &b;
    pS = &s[0];

    printVar(pA, pB);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

***[edit 2] addressing some comments about actual content if uncomment 3rd printf

I get the following two run-time notices, then get no output for the printf in line 3:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Those vars are different than vars in the functions. Just post a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example.

Comment: @self, I will edit.  Left char in by mistake.

Comment: What values did you set `a` and `b` to in the complete program?  (Not `pA` and `pB`.)

Comment: "when "b" prints only using %p" What do you mean by that ? Your screenshot shows you get output.

Comment: Are you passing `&a`, `&b` to `printvar`?

Comment: Also I think you'll find that if you change `a` to `b` on line one of `printVar` it does in fact print something (you'll get a different large number).

Comment: To all commenters so far, I will post the whole code for clarity sake.  The variables are passed just as they are shown in the existing code though, that is a real output for what is seen now.

Comment: Please don't post screen shots where a simple textual copy would suffice.

Comment: @nos - I meant that as a comparison to "a".  i.e. I did not have to use the address specifier "%p"  for "a", it just printed something out using its normal specifier "%d", but "b" using "%f".

Comment: @Zack - Yes, changing a to b on the first line would print something, represented as an int,  why though does it not accept a %f and printf something as a float?

Comment: @JensGustedt - Usually a picture can result in much fewer words.  But I will consider for future.

Comment: @ryyker Uncomment that "parameter mismatch" line and it *does* print something for me.  (There is a compiler diagnostic, but it is not an error.)

Comment: @haccks - by now you have seen the updated post, and maybe some of the answers.  Still curious why using %f results in param mismatch: expecting double, found pointer to float.

Comment: @Zack - See the edit for exact errors (and sorry to Jens, am posting another picture)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have these parameters:

```
int *a, float *b
```

This:

```
printf("%d\n", a);
```

most likely treats the memory space occupied by `a` (which is of type `int*`) *as if* it were an object of type `int`. On many systems, that will give you an almost meaningful result. (Of course if you really want to print a pointer value, you need to cast it to `void*` and use `%p`, but you're asking about the behavior of your incorrect code, not how to fix it.)

Things can get strange if `int` and `int*` are not the same size, or if `int`s and pointers are passed differently as arguments (some CPUs have had dedicated address and/or floating-point registers, for example).

```
printf("%d  %p\n",   a,  b);
```

It's very likely that `void*` and `float*` have the same representation, though that's not guaranteed by the language. If `int` and `int*` happen to be the same size, and are passed using the same argument-passing convention, this will most likely print the contents of the pointer `a` as if it were an `int` object, and then print the value of `b` as a pointer.

```
//printf("%d  %f", a,  b);// but fails on parameter mismatch using %f
```

`"%f"` requires an argument of type `double`, *not* of type `float` (`float` arguments are promoted to `double` for variadic functions like `printf`).  *If* `int` and `int*` are the same size, *and* `double` and `float*` are the same size, *and* all these types are passed using the same argument-passing convention, then this will most likely print the value of the pointer object `a` as if it were an `int`, and the value of the pointer object `b` as if it were a `double` object. The latter is likely to give you floating-point value that's completely garbage, perhaps even a NaN or Infinity. But if any of these assumptions fail, `printf` will likely grab data off the stack (or from registers) in *some* order that may or may not match up with the argument values.

Every one of the above `printf` calls has undefined behavior, which means that, strictly speaking, you should have no expectations about what will happen -- even that the behavior is in any way consistent. Understanding what's going on under the covers can be useful in recognizing the cause of an error (ah, that garbage floating-point value looks similar to what I got when I messed up a format string last month), but not really for anything else.

```
printf("%d  %f\n"  ,  *a, *b);// prints normally (as expected)
```

Ah, that's more like it -- but if this is executed after the previous calls, their undefined behavior may mess things up so badly that even this doesn't work. Also, looking at your entire program, the variables `a` and `b` in `main` (whose addresses are passed to `printVar`) are not initialized, so even in the best case `*a` and `*b` are garbage. Thanks to haccks for pointing this out in a comment.

Comment: First, thanks for recognizing I was interested in _the behavior of [my] incorrect code, not how to fix it._  And your observation: _float arguments are promoted to double for variadic functions like printf_ is probably the reason I am getting the behavior I have observed.  Thanks.

Comment: One more reason for undefined behavior of `printf("%d  %f\n"  ,  *a, *b);` is the value of `a` and `b` is not initialized in `main`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply because `b` is not a float, only `*b` is. It is just a lucky coincidence that pointers are actually integers (they might not be!) and thus printing them using `%d` specifier works (and results in something not quite meaningful).

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple -- because the argument types don't match the expected types from the format string, you get Undefined Behavior.  Anything at all could happen, so nothing should be surprising.

Several calling conventions don't pass floating-point parameters on the stack; rather, they pass them through special floating-point registers, e.g. the x87 stack or SSE registers.  So when `printf` sees a `%f` format specifier, it tries to read a floating-point value from those locations, but when it sees a `%d` format specifier, it tries to read an integer off the stack.  When you pass in a pointer instead, the compiler passes that on the stack.

For example, here's a simple function:

```
void printVars(float a, float *p)
{
  printf("%f\n", a);
  printf("%p\n", p);
}
```

And here's an annotated version of its disassembly on my x86-64 system, which passes floating-point values using the SSE registers `%xmm0` etc.:

```
00000000004004f4 <printVars>:
  ;;; Function prologue
  4004f4:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004f5:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004f8:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp

  ;;; Set up floating-point argument in %xmm0 register
  4004fc:   f3 0f 11 45 fc          movss  %xmm0,-0x4(%rbp)
  400501:   48 89 7d f0             mov    %rdi,-0x10(%rbp)
  400505:   f3 0f 10 45 fc          movss  -0x4(%rbp),%xmm0
  40050a:   0f 5a c0                cvtps2pd %xmm0,%xmm0
  ;;; Set up format string argument (%rdi) and call printf
  40050d:   b8 3c 06 40 00          mov    $0x40063c,%eax
  400512:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400515:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  40051a:   e8 d1 fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <printf@plt>

  ;;; Set up format string argument (%rdi) and pointer argument (%rsi) amd
  ;;; call printf
  40051f:   b8 40 06 40 00          mov    $0x400640,%eax
  400524:   48 8b 55 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rdx
  400528:   48 89 d6                mov    %rdx,%rsi
  40052b:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  40052e:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400533:   e8 b8 fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <printf@plt>

  ;;; Function epilogue
  400538:   c9                      leaveq 
  400539:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: Adam - Referring to Keith Thompson's answer, where he points out that a float is promoted to a double in veriadic functions, on what line in your answer can this promotion be seen (I am not familiar with using, or how to interpret disassemblers)

Comment: @ryyker: It happens in the [`cvtps2pd` instruction](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/iscenter-new/mpc/altix/altixdata/opt/intel/vtune/doc/users_guide/mergedProjects/analyzer_ec/mergedProjects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc55.htm), which converts two single-precision values into two double-precision values.

Answer (score 1):

Let us examine the code line by line

```
void printVar(int *a, float *b, char *s)
{
    printf("%d\n", a);            // here, printf print address of a as an int
    printf("%d  %p\n",   a,  b);  // address of b is not a float number
    printf("%d  %f\n"  ,  *a, *b);// *a is a int, *b is a float number
}
```

Comment: Technically 1/ and 2/ are undefined behavior, the type passed in for `a` doesn't match the format string.

Comment: You are right, but many compilers are just too nice to users :)

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of this modification of your program may be enlightening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printVar(int *a, float *b)
{
    printf("%d %e %p\n", a, a, a);
    printf("%d %e %p\n", b, b, b);
    printf("%d %e %p\n", *a, *a, *a);
    printf("%d %e %p\n", *b, *b, *b);
}
int
main(void)
{
  int a = 0x44444444;
  float b = 5.019220152e+33;
  printVar(&a, &b);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your run not result in runtime errors with this exact code? - I get the same error (param mismatch) on your line 1, 2, 3, on the second param and on line 4, first param.

Comment: Not sure why someone down voted this - It did provide some insight to what I was seeing.

Comment: No, I get no runtime errors at all (the compiler does complain about every incorrect parameter, but those are warnings).  I'm on a different operating system, though (MacOS).  I would expect runtime errors like the ones you get *only* from a special debug-instrumented C library; it must be adding significant overhead.